# How to send email using IP address?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am trying to send a test email from my IIS it has SMTP installed, but I am confused how to use IP address to send email.
Here is my code

```
SmtpClient m = new SmtpClient();
m.Host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; // my IP address.
m.Port = 25;
m.Send("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "mymailID@gmail.com", "Test", "This is a test email.....");
```

This code giving error

> The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail
>   address.

**UPDATE**

I am new to email sending concept.

Comment: Your IP address will be automatically included in the e-mail headers, don't worry. However, if your purpose is to appear from a different IP address, this technique is called spoofing, and can be illegal in soume countries/activities

Comment: @Mihalis Bagos : No no I am not looking for spoofing. But my code giving error why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the from address:

```
m.Send("FROM EMAIL ADDRESS HERE", "mymailID@gmail.com", "Test", "This is a test email.....");
```

[**Documentation Send(string, string, string, string)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1s04he7.aspx)

Chances are you've received email from `robot@domain.com` with instructions

> Do Not Reply to this Email

It seems like this would be your best bet, depending on if your mail server wants an authenticate address or not. For example, www.domainY.com, will only send domainY.com email address. There can be a lot of rules or no rules, but that can be for another time.

Comment: I am sending it from my IIS so how can I get `FROM EMAIL ADDRESS`?

Comment: Make it up, like `do-not-reply@domain.com`

Comment: Actually I don't have domain name I have only IP address, so without domain how I can send email?

Comment: You can create an email account, using gmail or whatever. Then just use that - Anderson_Server@gmail.com or whatever

Comment: I am trying same functionality like those website which send email but can't receive like you said `do-not-reply@domain.com`. How they achieve this? I think they send it using IIS but how?

Comment: Seriously, you can just make up anything so long as it looks like an email address.

Comment: now I am getting this error `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:25`

Comment: That's a new question. But you need to make sure that you don't have a firewall blocking port 25 on your server

Comment: my firewall is disabled. I know I am irritating you sorry for that. can you give me any link which explain these things clearly?

Comment: Then you don't have a listening mail server at that IP address

Answer (score 2):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1s04he7.aspx), the first argument to `Send()` should be the From address.  In emails, this is another email address.  You're giving it an IP, not an email.

An IP address can be used as the hostname portion of an email address.  For example:

```
webmaster@192.168.0.1
```

(Though I doubt modern mail systems will like that, and many may flag it as spam or in some other way treat it as unwanted mail.)  But it can not be used as the entire address.

Comment: what is `webmaster` is it a keyword?

Comment: @Anderson: A random example of an email address, common in the days of yore.  You don't have to use it.  (In fact, I recommend using a real email address so you can get bounced messages to that address in the event of an error at the receiving server.)  I also don't recommend using the example IP I used :)

Answer (score 0):

The from address is whatever you want it to.  I usually pick clever or descriptive names that describe the email that is being sent.  Emails sent back to this address will end up in never land, however.

If you are using smtp you should have an smtp server such as server.domain.com or something of that nature.